# How is the mantra pronounced for Vishnu?

Tags: mantras, identification-request

I need some correction for a mantra which I heard recently but unable to find the script. So I am putting down on what I heard but it may not be the correct in terms of language but it would give an idea of the mantra that I am talking about ...so the mantra is

SRIMATE NARAYANA Ahinmam khirma khetre parvate hema utchiktaya rangathaya ......

There are mistakes in script but I would like to know the correct form of this mantra for the presiding deity Pooja. It would be great if you can respond with the correct version of it.

Comment: Please edit the question to make it objective. Right now, it looks like personal advice question and such questions are off-topic.

Comment: Do you have this mantra in Devanagari script. English is very erroneous , if Devanagari script is available to you it can be corrected.

Comment: Sorry Anurag.I dont have any thing as I did not find the written script in any language on Internet. However I can transform the same by using converter & the version is here for you...सृिमते नारायाणा अहिनमाम खिरमा खेतरे पर्वते आमुृुतात्मे हेमा उतचिकताया  रंगनाथआया....